# Should i enable synchronous_commit option on single node master database server?

Tags: postgresql-performance, enterprisedb

I have an EnterpriseDB 11 database server and not clustered. It's a single master database server with no replica. I see an option named synchronous_commit option on the postgres.conf file. It has **synchronous_commit=remote_apply** and on running huge queries it is causing performance degradation.

**So should i hash it ?**

Answer (score 0):

Well for a single node, it should be hashed.